# taxonomy menu links change with path

Tags: routes, 7, uri, taxonomy-terms

Is there any way to change taxonomy menu links depending on path? I have a Taxonomy menu in a block with different levels and depending on path I would like to change the taxonomy level depending where the user is. Context maybe?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you ACTUALLY want [Menu block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) in tandem.

> So… have you ever used the Main and Secondary menu links feature on
>   your theme and wondered “how the hell do I display any menu items
>   deeper than that?”

I *think* the following is what you're after, but the module is pretty configurable if I'm mistaken.

Create your taxonomy menu as you normally would, and instead of putting that menu block in the sidebar (or wherever), put a menu block generated block there. Then in the settings for the menu block click *Advanced*. Under this tab, there's now a chekbox titles *Make the starting level follow the active menu item*. If you check that box, then the top level will reflect the current page.

[image: Menu block settings]